# Insertion of data in salesforce from android native app

Tags: java, android, sdk, salesforce, jira-rest-api

Insertion of data in `salesforce` from android native app
- we have tried to insert the data from the android native app to `salesforce` database. We are able to fetch the data from the `salesforce` database but unable to insert the data in `salesforce` database from native android app.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @prasann dubey : Put up your code trials. In StackOverflow its like NO CODE , NO HELP !